# Is 'the same (thing) as (possessive pronoun)...' grammatically acceptable?

Tags: pronouns, relative-pronouns, personal-pronouns

Swan's book explains:

> In **short answers** we use **me**, **him**, etc. (informal) or **I**,
> **he**, etc. **with a verb** (more formal). The same thing happens after **as** and **than**.
>
> **Informal**
>
> - I've got the same number as **him**
>
> **Formal**
>
> - I've got the same number as **he has**.

Now, my question is, why doesn't the informal form like this:

> - I've got the same number as **his**.

This is the reason why I think like this: My logical thinking (as a learner) prefer [... as **possessive pronoun** (his)] to [... as **personal pronoun** (him)] because it refers directly to **the thing (theirs)** rather than **the person**.

Another example:

> I have the same eyes as my mother.

Or

> I have the same eyes as my mother's.

In conclusion, is 'the same (thing) as (possessive pronoun)...' correct?

Comment: **His** is not a reflexive pronoun, it is a possessive pronoun. The reflexive pronoun corresponding to he/him/his is **himself**. (And no, using a reflexive pronoun here would not be be correct.)

Comment: *As* is being used here to compare actions between two people. The action is having a number.

Comment: ***He is** the same age as **me, His age** is the same as **mine*** - NOT ***He is** the same age as **mine*** or ***His age** is the same as **me***

Comment: @CanadianYankee Thank you. I was a bit confused differentiating those two pronouns. I'll edit the question soon.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for your comment. Since I use [**I have** the same...] construction in my example, which one is correct? Is it **me** or **mine**?

Comment: Using ***to have*** instead of ***to be*** is the same as the *first* example in my previous comment. So *He **has** the same age as me* is just a less common alternative to *He **is** the same age as me* (we normally use ***to be*** in *I **am** the same age as him*, but for something like a name, it's *I **have** the same name as him*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not refer to these a "formal" and "informal" forms, but as full and shortened forms.

> - I've got the same number as he has.
> - I've got the same number as he does.
> - I've got the same number as him.

Each of these is correct, and often used by fluent speakers. The meaning of each is the same. The third is a shortened form, and might be more likely in casual, informal use, and more likely in spoke than in written English.

> I've got the same number as his.

can also be used, it is short for

> I've got the same number as his number.

In this case the meanings are the same as  the previous three forms. This conbstriction can be used in other contexts. In fact

> - I've got the same X as he has.
> - I've got the same X as he does.
> - I've got the same X as him.
> - I've got the same X as his.
> - I have the same X as he has.
> - I have the same X as he does.
> - I have the same X as him.
> - I have the same X as his.

are all valid, and mean the same thing, whatever X may be.

Now when the sentence starts with a possessive form (as none of the examples on the question do) then it should use a possessive for the target of the comparison:

> - My number is the same as his
> - His professor is the same as mine.
> - Your shirt is just like mine.

are all correct.

Comment: Google Books shows me only a single example of *got the same number as **his*** where I can read the full context. And that context is *“How come your horse has got the same number as his?”*, where possessive ***his*** clearly refers to *his **horse***. I don't think many native speakers would use the possessive there if all it referred to was *[the same number as] **his number*** - in *that* context it's normally just *the same number as **him***.